# How can I cycle on instances of heterogenous classes to call methods with identical name and parameters?

Tags: c++, methods, c++98

If I have:

```
class A {
    void foo();
};

class B {
    void foo();
};
```

Is there a way to collect instances of type `A` and `B` to cycle on them to call the `foo()` method? For example using some macro or pointers and some special data type? Or collecting function pointers?

The following pseudocode might give an idea of what I mean.

```
int main () {
    A a;
    B b;

    hypothetical_container_t hypothetical_container; 
    hypothetical_container.push_back(a);
    hypothetical_container.push_back(b);

    [...]//Do stuff with a, do other stuff with b

    for (hypothetical_container_t::iterator ii = hypothetical_container.begin(); ii != hypothetical_container.end(); ++ii) {
        ii->foo();
    }
}
```

The use case is having a bunch of `boost::shared_ptr` variables with different type T and call `.reset()` on all of them. (I know in this example calling reset wouldn't be necessary).

Comment: maybe trying functor?

Comment: Are the types known at compile time? If so, you could use a tuple for the container, and iterate with a variadic template. If not, you'll need a virtual function in a common base class.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The types are known at compile time, however I have to stay within C++98 (I edited the tags)

Comment: @Antonio use Boost.Fusion `for_each`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the option of changing the classes A and B, I would recommend going with the [answer by @mstbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29654052/434551).

If you don't have that option, I have the following suggestion.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    void foo(){}
};

struct B {
    void foo(){}
};

struct Wrapper
{
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <typename T> struct WrapperImpl : Wrapper
{
   WrapperImpl(T& obj) : obj_(obj) {}
   void foo() {obj_.foo();}
   T& obj_;
};

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Wrapper> makeWrapper(T& t)
{
   return std::unique_ptr<Wrapper>(new WrapperImpl<T>(t));
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Wrapper>> v;
   A a;
   B b;
   v.push_back(makeWrapper(a));
   v.push_back(makeWrapper(b));

   for ( auto& item : v )
   {
      item->foo();
   }
}
```

Comment: There are still a couple of C++11 features used (but I think nothing forbids to use `boost::shared_ptr` in place of `std::unique_ptr`, and the `for` cycle is just a matter of rewording), but your solution looks quite amazing!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a virtual class:

```
virtual class C {
    public:
        virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class A : public C {
    virtual void foo();
};

class B : public C {
    virtual void foo();
};
```

Then in main you can have:

```
A a;
B b;

std::vector<C*> vec;
vec.push_back(&a);
vec.push_back(&b);
```

And then you can iterate and call the foo method, which all members of the vector are guaranteed to implement.

WRT boost::shared_ptr, I'm not as familiar with but I would imagine you could do something like:

```
boost::shared_ptr<C> a(new A);
boost::shared_ptr<C> b(new B);

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<C>> vec;
```

Comment: You'll need to store pointers. `push_back(a)` will attempt to create a `C` object by slicing `a`. Luckily that will give a friendly compile-time error, rather than obscure run-time problems, since `C` is abstract.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but what I mean is that I have to call the `reset()` method for some `boost::shared_ptr<T>` with different `T`. The problem is not `T`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I cycle on instances of heterogenous classes to call methods
>   with identical name and parameters?

This calls for template !

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void    chain_call_reset()
{
}

template<typename Arg, typename ... Rest>
void    chain_call_reset(Arg&& arg, Rest&&... rest)
{
  arg.reset();
  chain_call_reset(rest...);
}

int     main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<int>  ptr = std::make_shared<int>(42);
  std::shared_ptr<char>  ptr2 = std::make_shared<char>('c');
  std::shared_ptr<float>  ptr3 = std::make_shared<float>(4.2);

  chain_call_reset(ptr, ptr2, ptr3);

  std::cout << std::boolalpha << !!ptr << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << !!ptr2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << !!ptr3 << std::endl;
}
```

In case there is no common hierarchy between your types, templates is the way to go :)

Comment: @Antonio The boost way to mimic this feature is to implement overload of the function for a reasonable enough parameter number (say 10, 15 or 20) which should be enough in most cases :)

Answer (score 1):

Your task requires type elision. Boost::any is a good example for that.
A simple one for calling a common function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Any
{
    // Content
    // =======

    private:
    class ContentInterface
    {
        public:
        virtual ~ContentInterface() {}
        virtual void call() const {}
    };

    template <typename T>
    class Content : public ContentInterface
    {
        private:
        T& m_object;

        public:
        Content(T& object)
        :   m_object(object)
        {}

        virtual void call() const { m_object.foo(); }
    };

    // use boost here:    
    typedef std::shared_ptr<ContentInterface> content_ptr;

    // Constructionn
    // =============

    public:
    Any()
    {}

    template<typename T>
    Any(T& object)
    :   m_content(new Content<T>(object))
    {}

    void call() const { m_content->call(); }

    private:
    content_ptr m_content;
};

struct A {
    void foo() { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B {
    void foo() { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

int main(void)
{
    typedef std::vector<Any> container;
    A a;
    B b;
    container v;
    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(b);
    for(container::const_iterator pos = v.begin(); pos != v.end(); ++pos)
        pos->call();
}
```

An alternative is std::function with std::bind (again, use boost functionality, in C++98):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    typedef std::function<void ()> function;
    typedef std::vector<function> container;
    A a;
    B b;
    container v;

    v.push_back(std::bind(&A::foo, a));
    v.push_back(std::bind(&B::foo, b));
    for(container::const_iterator pos = v.begin(); pos != v.end(); ++pos)
        (*pos)();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to variadic templates you can use `boost::fusion` :

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/make_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>

struct  reset
{
  template<typename T>
  void operator()(T& t) const
  {
    t.reset();
  }
};

int     main()
{
  boost::shared_ptr<int>  ptr = boost::make_shared<int>(42);
  boost::shared_ptr<char>  ptr2 = boost::make_shared<char>('c');
  boost::shared_ptr<float>  ptr3 = boost::make_shared<float>(4.2);


  boost::fusion::vector<boost::shared_ptr<int>&, boost::shared_ptr<char>&, boost::shared_ptr<float>& > vec
    = boost::fusion::make_vector(boost::ref(ptr), boost::ref(ptr2), boost::ref(ptr3));

  boost::fusion::for_each(vec, reset());

  std::cout << std::boolalpha << !!ptr << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << !!ptr2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << !!ptr3 << std::endl;
}
```